# Routing and Remote access rule not being applied internally (Windows SBS)

Tags: windows, rras, windows-sbs

I have a Microsoft Small Business Server.

I have pointed an external domain name to the external fixed IP address for the server.

In routing and remote access I have defined a service for our subversion server as follows:

Incoming port: 8443

Private address: 192.168.10.5

Outgoing port: 8443

192.168.10.5 is our development server, not the SBS (which is at 192.168.10.1)

This rule works correctly if I am not on our internal network. However if I am on the internal network this rule does not get applied.

What can I do/set so this rule is applied both internally and externally (so users with laptops et, don't keep having to change the URL by which they access the subversion server)

Not sure what other info you may need, so please let me know if more details are required.

T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK,

I've got it working, however I'm not 100% happy with the solution as it seems cumbersome. So any advice will still be gratefully received.

I've created a forward lookup zone on the internal DNS server for our domain name and have added a new host which maps the domain name to the internal server. This now works internally and externally.

This of course means I have to maintain two DNS records for this domain which is hardly optimal, but at least it works for now!